# docker --rm only if exit code is zero

Tags: docker

Is there a way to tell `docker run` to remove the container's file system (`--rm`) but only if the exit code for the container is 0? I like the idea of keeping around unexpected exits to debug later on, but the vast majority of my containers will run successfully (and I have many of them), so I want to avoid keep around the container's file system.

EDIT: Clarification
A user can provide the `--rm` flag directly to `docker run` so that upon exit of the container, the file system is removed. You can remove this manually later on, but in my case, I'm scheduling a large number of containers to run using unix's `at` command. I would like each container to handle removing its own file system, when done, hence the `--rm` flag I'm adding to my command. However, if the container exits with a non-zero exit code, I would like to keep the file system around to debug afterwards. So my question is whether this is possible to do.

Comment: Sounds like a feature request, or possibly a pull request to submit to docker. Moby is their upstream open source project you can contribute to.

Comment: It looks like someone suggested you could do this by hand using `docker rm`, and you did not like this idea. However, you could get a container to do this on a Cron schedule, using the logic you specify, so it is automatic. The exit code is kept in `docker inspect` data.

Comment: That's a fair alternative. But the question was not, is this somehow possible at all (of course it is), but can this be directly specified when the docker container is launched. It's now clear that this feature is not available.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't completely understand your question. If you want to remove inactive containers, you can run the command:

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

Comment: clarified question.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think Docker supports conditional RM. 
You can clean up successful containers afterwards though.